# Reading a CSV file and get a value that I can put in a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.10

I have a csv file that I can read and print

```
 reference  radius  diameter  length sfcefin  pltol  mitol     sfcetrement
0      jnl1      15      30.0      35     Rz2    0.0  -0.03  Stellite Spray
1      jnl2      28      56.0      50     NaN    NaN    NaN             NaN
2      jnl3      10      20.0      25     NaN    NaN    NaN             NaN
3   jnlfce1      15       NaN      15     NaN    NaN    NaN             NaN
4   jnlfce2      28       NaN      13     NaN    NaN    NaN             NaN
5   jnlfce3      28       NaN      18     NaN    NaN    NaN             NaN
6   jnlfce4      10       NaN      10     NaN    NaN    NaN             NaN
```

I have managed to isolate and print a specific row using

```
df1 = df[df['reference'].str.contains(feature)]

  reference  radius  diameter  length sfcefin  pltol  mitol sfcetrement
1      jnl2      28      56.0      50     NaN    NaN    NaN         NaN
```

I now want to select the radius column and put the value into a variable
I have tried the similar technique on the output of the `df1` but with no success

```
value = df1[df1['radius']]
print(value)
```

Has anyone any more suggestions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take a look in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help on using Markdown to format your posts for future reference. I've [edit]ed this one as an example for you.

Comment: Try: `value = df1['radius']`

Comment: value = df1['radius'] – 
Chrysophylaxs
 This gets me 1    28
Name: radius, dtype: int64     so I need to put the 28 into a variable

Comment: value = df1['radius']

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.loc` and simply do:

```
value = df.loc[df1.reference.str.contains(feature), 'radius']
```

Comment: Thankyou SomeDude this will do me nicely - very neat